# Can one specific Amiibo create 2 differents saves on 2 different Fire Emblem Fate Cartridges?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

Me and my mate are sharing a bunch of amiibos for our Super Smash 4 Game and thought it would be great to have Ike/Marth on our Fire Emblem games. However, we are not sure if the fact of creating a ''IKe'' save on one cartirdge will disable the possibility to create one in our other 3ds game (we each have one Fire Emblem Fate game).

Is the unlock of amiibo character a ''usable once'' possibility per amiibo?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the same Amiibo across multiple saves and multiple cartridges.**

I have Marth, Ike, Lucina, and Robin and recruited all four. I then lent them to my brother and he was able to do the same thing. I then recruited them again in a different file.

It appears that FE Fates only performs a read operation on the amiibo to aquire the data and does not write anything to it. I suppose Nintendo's way to prevent abusive sharing is to require each amiibo to be used three times before recruitment is possible with each use separated by a battle.